# How to design bar chart on SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I want to create reports like below picture's report on SSRS.

Yellow parts mean `SET_PHASE`,
Green parts mean `PROD_PHASE`

[image: Expected]

And my query result like this:

[image: Query]

I want to show for per line, all order and I want to show for per order, SETUP and PRODUCTION depends on duratıon time.

`SET_PHASE`'s duration time is `SET_DURATION`,

`PROD_PHASE`'s duration time is `PROD_DURATION`

I hope so my query is clear :) Could you help me about issue?

---

Answer:

Hello Alan,

Current situation I have just these data:

```
PROD100059335   SETUP   PRODUCTION  1   14  LINE 4
PROD100058991   SETUP   PRODUCTION  1   5   LINE 6
PROD100059259   SETUP   PRODUCTION  2   24  LINE 4
PROD100059188   SETUP   PRODUCTION  1   3   LINE 2
PROD100059248   SETUP   PRODUCTION  1   15  LINE 2
PROD100059055   SETUP   PRODUCTION  2   23  LINE 2
PROD100058754   SETUP   PRODUCTION  5   18  LINE 6
```

And If I use your query I just show "PROD100058754", "PROD100059259", "PROD100059055" these order. I don't understand why other data lost.

until "DECLARE @n TABLE(n int)" part I can show other data. but after that I can not show.

And I applied procedure on SSRS my report shows like this:

[image]

I couldn't do correctly and I don't know how can I fix them:(

for example "PROD100059259" this order normally has setup phase but on the report I don't have yellow field.

Do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: This is possible (probably!). I've built something similar myself. The problem I can see you facing is the scale of the data. We would have to build a matrix report with each column representing a fixed amount of time. Looking at your sample data, and assuming the data is in either minutes/seconds or hours/minutes then PROD100057968 has a setup time of 1 minute and a production time of 192 hours which is 11000 times bigger. Either the setup time would be lost on the report or the report would required tens of thousands of columns, which is not feasible.

Comment: following on, you could compromise by scaling everything so it fits into 256 columns (SSRS Matrix maximum) but it would not be accurate. If this sounds OK let me know and I will see if I can put something together

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. ı tried to use stacked bar. maybe I can do to use stacked bar but still I have some issue. my values 1 is SET_PHASE, value 2 is PROD_PHASE. category group is LINE and Series Group is STR_ORDER_ID but if I created to like this I couldn't use duration time and I don't know how to change color green and yellow for every order and I should to put gap every distinct order. Could you help me about these issues? and I don't know by this way(stacked bar) is it make sence?

Comment: Again, this would be possible but you'll have the same issue. When you have a small setup time and long production time, the setup time will be so small you just won't see it. I'll see if I can come up with something that will get the data in a sensible format and then you can choose what you want to do with it from there.

Comment: [enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Msri.png

Comment: I did like above the picture. and you are right I will face same issue but I couldn't find how to put duration time condition on chart. if I put duration condition, I can show our costumer. And we can find another option. I should change footer axis title field to setup duration and production duration. Do you know How could I do?

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do but try creating a simple dataset containing just the two values from row 7 of your sample data. Then add a stacked bar chart to display this data and you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here is an attempt to give you what you want but there are a few caveats:

1. The durations are scaled and no operation can take less than 1 time slot so the setup vs production duration is only approximate
2. I haven't found a good way of labelling each bar so I've used tooltips

**First the code**... I've added lots of comments so hopefully you can follow it thru, it's based on your sample data.

**NOTE: I've update the table as it now seems like you are using integer durations rather than the 00:00 format from your first example.**

```
-- CREATE A TEST TABLE AND POPULATE IT
DECLARE @data TABLE(STR_ORDER_ID varchar(20), SET_DURATION varchar(10), PROD_DURATION varchar(10), Set_decimal int, Prod_Decimal int, Line varchar(10))

INSERT INTO @data
VALUES
('PROD100059335', NULL, NULL, 1, 14, 'LINE 4'),
('PROD100058991', NULL, NULL,1, 5, 'LINE 6'),
('PROD100059259', NULL, NULL,2, 24, 'LINE 4'),
('PROD100059188', NULL, NULL,1, 3, 'LINE 2'),
('PROD100059248', NULL, NULL,1, 15, 'LINE 2'),
('PROD100059055', NULL, NULL,2, 23, 'LINE 2'),
('PROD100058754', NULL, NULL,5, 18, 'LINE 6')

DECLARE @Gap int = 2 -- determines how many columns we use to separate each order

-- ASSUME durations are in hours/minutes or minutes/seconds and convert them to decimal minutes or decimal seconds respectively

-- COMMENTED THIS AS WE NO LONGER NEED IT. No longer required as durations are now integer values.
--UPDATE d 
--    SET 
--        Set_decimal = (CAST(LEFT(d.SET_DURATION, len(d.SET_DURATION)-3) AS INT) * 60) +  CAST(RIGHT(d.SET_DURATION, 2) AS INT)  ,
--        Prod_Decimal = (CAST(LEFT(d.PROD_DURATION, len(d.PROD_DURATION)-3) AS INT) * 60) +  CAST(RIGHT(d.PROD_DURATION, 2) AS INT) 
--FROM @data d


-- CREATE A NORMALISED TABLE, this will just help to make the next steps simpler
DECLARE @normData TABLE(RowId INT IDENTITY (1,1), Line varchar(10), STR_ORDER_ID varchar(20), OperationOrder int, Operation varchar(10), Duration int)
INSERT INTO @normData (Line, STR_ORDER_ID, OperationOrder, Operation, Duration)
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT Line, STR_ORDER_ID, 1 as OperationOrder , 'SET' as Operation , Set_decimal FROM @data 
UNION
SELECT Line, STR_ORDER_ID, 2 , 'PROD' , Prod_decimal FROM @data 
UNION
SELECT Line, STR_ORDER_ID, 3 , 'GAP' , @Gap FROM @data )  u -- this adds dummy data that will act as gaps in hte timeline. Change 5 to whatever value suits you best
    ORDER BY Line, STR_ORDER_ID, OperationOrder

-- find the largest line running total duration per line and scale it to fit to 240 (so we dont go over 256 column limit in SSRS)
DECLARE @MaxDur INT = (SELECT MAX(rt) FROM (
                        select  *
                            , SUM(Duration) OVER(PARTITION BY Line ORDER BY Line, STR_ORDER_ID, OperationOrder) AS Rt
                         from @normData) mRt)


-- Now scale the values back so they fit but don't let any value become less than 1
IF @MaxDur > 240
    BEGIN
        UPDATE nd 
            SET Duration = CASE WHEN nd.Duration / (@MaxDur/240) <1 THEN 1 ELSE nd.Duration / (@MaxDur/240) END
            FROM @normData nd
    END

/* check what we have so far by uncommenting this bit
select  *
    , SUM(Duration) OVER(PARTITION BY Line ORDER BY Line, STR_ORDER_ID, OperationOrder) AS Rt
 from @normData
--*/    

-- ================================================================ --
-- At this point you 'may' have enough data to plot a bar chart. == --
-- ================================================================ --

-- CREATE A SIMPLE NUMBERS TABLE, we'll need this to act as our time series
DECLARE @n TABLE(n int)
DECLARE @i int  = 0
DECLARE @t int  = @MaxDur --(SELECT max(Duration) +5 FROM @normData) -- simple loop counter target set to slightly bigger than our highest duration
WHILE @i<@t
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @n SELECT @i
        SET @i = @i +1
    END

-- Join our numbers table to our real data
-- This will give us at least 1 row per time slot and associated activity during that time slot.
-- We can plot this driectly as a matrix.
SELECT * 
    FROM @n n
        LEFT JOIN ( 
                -- Sub queries below give use a runnintg total, we then join this back to itself to get the previous 
                -- running total and this will give us the 'time range' for each operation.
                SELECT 
                    a.*
                    , ISNULL(b.Rt,0)+1 AS TimeStart
                    , a.RT AS TimeEnd
                    FROM
                    (SELECT *
                            , SUM(Duration) OVER(PARTITION BY Line ORDER BY Line, STR_ORDER_ID, OperationOrder) AS Rt
                         from @normData
                    ) a
                LEFT JOIN 
                    (SELECT *
                            , SUM(Duration) OVER(PARTITION BY Line ORDER BY Line, STR_ORDER_ID, OperationOrder) AS Rt
                         from @normData
                    ) b
                    ON a.RowId = b.RowId + 1 and a.Line = b.Line 
                ) d
            ON n.n between d.TimeStart and d.TimeEnd
    ORDER BY Line, STR_ORDER_ID, OperationOrder, n, TimeStart, TimeEnd
```

You can use the code above in your dataset.

**The report design:**
The report is very simple. It's a matrix with a single row group based on `Line` and a single column group based on `n` which is our time slot number.

I've added a blank row to act as a spacer between the 'bars'.

[image]

The expression of the cell background is

```
=SWITCH(
Fields!OperationOrder.Value = 1, "Yellow",
Fields!OperationOrder.Value = 2, "Green",
Fields!OperationOrder.Value = 3, Nothing,
True, Nothing
)
```

There is also a tooltip which displays STR_ORDER_ID and the operation name.

You get the following output.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help Alan! :) but still I couldn't do  report. I don't understand how I create matrix report?

Comment: just right-click the design surface, Insert/Matrix. Drag LINE into the left column, Drag N into the right column **header** and optionally drag 'Operation' into the data cell (bottom right labelled data when its blank). That should create the row and column groups. You can see the groups at the bottom of the design area. Once that's done, test it, you'll see the operation names in each cell. Then delete the data cell as you don't need it, set the data column width to something small like 0.3cm and set the background color expression to the SWITCH statement in the example.

Comment: Hello Alan, I couldn't answer below. that's why I edited my question on above. Do you have any suggestion for my issue_

Comment: There was a bug in the original code which I have corrected, I've also changed some other parts as the format of the data is not the same as it was before.

Comment: Thanks a lot about your help :) I did like this but on productıon environment my procedure running very slowly that's why I thought maybe I can use range(gantt) chart but if I use gantt chart I face to this problem [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43939415/how-to-add-two-different-values-on-ganttrange-bar-chart-in-ssrs)  do you give me any suggestıon about this issue?