# how to add two different values on gantt(range bar) chart in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, charts, range, gantt-chart

I would like to report like this:
I want to show orders for every line and order has setup(yellow) and productıon(green) phase. Setup and Phase widths depends on actual_start_time and actual_end_time.

[image]

My query result is like this:

[image]

I tried to create report stacked bar, you can see this link: [How to design bar chart on SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43805603/how-to-design-bar-chart-on-ssrs)

but if I create like this my report running very slowly.

that's why I try to create report use range (Gantt) chart.
report design:

[image]

and report preview:

[image]

I want to show productıon and setup phase side by side for every order but I couldn't show. Do you give me any suggestıon about this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: When you say depends do you mean a Functional Dependency or a Conditional Functional Dependency?

Comment: I mean Set_Phase's interval should be between SET_ACT_START and SET_ACT_END time. in range bar I used in series properties top_value:SET_ACT_START , bottom_value: SET_ACT_END, category_field:[SP_LINE]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Chart Series "CustomAttributes" set to "DrawSideBySide=False".

Click on any of the bars in your chart in design mode and under "General" there is "CustomAttributes". Set the value to "False".